# How to pass a value inside js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this `NULL VALUE` ON `$_SESSION` inside my compare.php
Do you know how to fix this?

Thank you

The js function :

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {   
        var chkArray = [];   
        $('#container').html('');

        //put the selected checkboxes values in chkArray[]
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
            chkArray.push($(this).val());
        });


        //If chkArray is not empty show the <div> and create the list
        if(chkArray.length !== 0) {
            $('#container').show();           
            $.each(chkArray, function(i, val) { 
                $('<p>').text(chkArray[i]).appendTo('#container');
            });


            $('#rectButton').on('click', function (e) {     
             $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url : "http://localhost/shop/ext/ajax/products_compare/compare.php",
                data : {product_id:chkArray},
/*
                success : function(resp){
                    alert("Product is added to be compared" );
                }
*/                
             });
           });

        }else{
            $('#container').hide();   
            $('#container').html('');
        }
    });    
})             
</script>

<button id="rectButton" class="btn"><a href="compare.php">Compare</a></button>
```

my ajax file

```
 $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

 if(!is_array($_SESSION['ids'])) {
   $_SESSION['ids'] = [];
 } else {
   array_push($_SESSION['ids'], $product_id);
 }
```

the ajax file result is :

```
product_id[]: 12
product_id[]: 10
product_id[]: 9
```

my file compare.php on the ajax result.

```
var_dump($_SESSION] ===> NULL
var_dump($_SESSION]N['ids']; ===> NULL


result I see:
array(1) { ["ids"]=> array(5) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "10" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(1) "9" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "9" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "12" [1]=> string(1) "9" } [4]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "12" [1]=> string(2) "11" [2]=> string(1) "9" } } }
```

good result to have :

```
[4]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "12" [1]=> string(2) "11" [2]=> string(1) "9" }
```

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the beginning of  both scripts?

Comment: Not related to the problem you describe, but `$_SESSION['ids'] = [];` should be `$_SESSION['ids'] = [$product_id];`. Otherwise, the first AJAX call won't save its product ID.

Comment: `$_POST['product_id']` is an array, not a single product ID. So `$_SESSION['ids']` will be a 2-dimensional array. Is that what you really want?

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind an event handler inside another event handler. Every time you change a checkbox, you add another click handler to `#rectButton`, so it will run multiple times when you click.

Comment: @Barmar. I tried with that $_SESSION['ids'] = [$product_id];. but the result is always on null on var_dump($_SESSION);

Comment: @Barmar How to change that ?

Comment: Like I said, those issues are not related to the problem. The only reason I can think for `$_SESSION` being empty is that you didn't do `session_start()` at the very beginning of all the scripts.

Comment: You have to do it before you do anything that could produce output.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I have I include the session_start(), works ! tk. About this : It's almost always wrong to bind ==> How to witre the script correctly ?

Comment: @Barmar : I includedd the result above

Comment: Put the `click` handler at top-level, and declare the `chkArray` variable outside the handlers so the `change` handler can assign to it and the click handler can use it when it calls $.ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$_POST['product_id']` is an array, you shouldn't push the entire array onto the session variable as a single item, that's why you're getting a 2-dimensional array. You should simply assign the new array to the session variable, since it contains all the items that the user has checked.

```
$_SESSION['ids'] = $_POST['product_id'];
```

You shouldn't bind the click handler inside the change handler. You should bind the two handlers independently, and they can both use a global `chkArray` variable.

```js
$(function() {
  var chkArray = [];
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    $('#container').html('');

    //put the selected checkboxes values in chkArray[]
    chkArray = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();

    //If chkArray is not empty show the <div> and create the list
    if (chkArray.length !== 0) {
      $('#container').show().html('');
      $.each(chkArray, function(i, val) {
        $('<p>').text(chkArray[i]).appendTo('#container');
      });
    } else {
      $('#container').hide().html('');
    }
  });

  $('#rectButton').on('click', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: "//localhost/shop/ext/ajax/products_compare/compare.php",
      data: {
        product_id: chkArray
      },
      /*
      success: function(resp) {
        alert("Product is added to be compared");
      }
      */
    });
  });

})
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for these explaination. It's more clear. I looking the result about 4 checkbobx id (12-11-10-9). the result inside the ajax file is var_dump($_SESSION['ids']) ==>array(1) { ["ids"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "10" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(1) "9" } } }
After more test it take always the last id 10 - 9. The other id are inside the session.

Comment: How are you calling the ajax file? The only AJAX you've posted is `compare.php`, is that something else?